# Setting New Time Problems in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set New Time in by follwoing :

```
var d = new Date('2011-04-11T' + dataRecord.StartTime);
// If the dataRecord.StartTime ='05:10:10' then d becomes
//    Date {Mon Apr 11 2011 05:10:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}
var e = new Date('2011-04-11T' + dataRecord.EndTime);
```

This is working fine in Mozilla ,but in case of chrome it is showing 5.30 Hours advance!!!
How could i change my code to work in all browsers??

Comment: Could you post the exact results you obtain on Chrome? It looks like it's using UTC instead of local time.

Comment: Chrome is adding hours based on client local time. For example if you are in +3 Timezone and trying to create date of '2011-04-11T15:00:00' you will get '2011-04-11T18:00:00'. To get rid of this problem i suggest you to stick to UTC time format so you will get same result in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this do the trick?

```
var d   = new Date('2011-04-11T05:10:10');
var utc = new Date(new Date().getTime());
d.setMinutes(utc.getTimezoneOffset() + d.getMinutes() );
console.log(d);
```

I just get the offset from the current browser and add them to the date you create first. The timezone offset is given in minutes...